# rayshader plot_gg stat(nlevel) issue

Tags: r, ggplot2, terra, rayshader

Based on the code below how can I fix this error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘terra’ 1.6-7 is being loaded, but >= 1.6.16 is required
In addition: Warning message:
`stat(nlevel)` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
ℹ Please use `after_stat(nlevel)` instead.
```

Code:

```
library(rayshader) # latest version 0.24.10

# 3D plotting with rayshader and ggplot2
ggdiamonds = ggplot(diamonds) +
stat_density_2d(aes(x = x, y = depth, fill = stat(nlevel)), 
                   geom = "polygon", n = 200, bins = 50,contour = TRUE) +  facet_wrap(clarity~.) +
scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "A")
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))

plot_gg(ggdiamonds, width = 5, height = 5, raytrace = FALSE, preview = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your version of terra needs updating:
`install.packages("terra")`

Comment: Yup, figured that out and ran into another issue while [updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74495687/terra-package-update-isssue) `terra`